# Where does source-map-loader fit into TypeScript compilation with Webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm adding TypeScript to the build process of a currently all-JavaScript web app whose build process is structured around Webpack. I've been following TypeScript's [Migrating from JavaScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html) article, and have a question about the suggested Webpack configuration¹, copied below for your convenience:

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "./dist/bundle.js",
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" }
        ],

        preLoaders: [
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    // Other options...
};
```

The presence of `awesome-typescript-loader` is of course required — we want to compile TypeScript, after all. My question is about `source-map-loader`, used here as a pre-loader. The article is pretty terse about its purpose, saying only:

> You can use `awesome-typescript-loader`, a TypeScript loader, combined with `source-map-loader` for easier debugging.

[Another article](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html) adds only a bit of extra information:

> Both of these dependencies will let TypeScript and Webpack play well together. `awesome-typescript-loader` helps Webpack compile your TypeScript code using the TypeScript’s standard configuration file named `tsconfig.json`. `source-map-loader` uses any sourcemap outputs from TypeScript to inform webpack when generating its own sourcemaps. This will allow you to debug your final output file as if you were debugging your original TypeScript source code.

Finally, [`source-map-loader`'s own README](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader/blob/master/README.md) says:

> `source-map-loader extracts` existing source maps from all JavaScript entries. This includes both inline source maps as well as those linked via URL. All source map data is passed to webpack for processing as per a chosen source map style specified by the devtool option in `webpack.config.js`.

Ok. So `source-map-loader` ingests source maps and provides them to Webpack. My question, though, is why should it be running as a pre-loader? Based on the second quote, above, it sounds like `source-map-loader` is supposed to pick up sourcemap outputs from TypeScript. If it runs as a pre-loader, though, [it runs before normal loaders](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-enforce), and I don't understand how it can use output from TypeScript.

Further, I was under the impression that Webpack doesn't deal with intermediate files — in the configuration, `source-map-loader` only loads `.jsx?` files. Doesn't that mean `source-map-loader` won't be invoked on the results of TypeScript compilation at all?

---

1: Note that this Webpack configuration uses outdated syntax, listing normal loaders in the `module.loaders` section, and pre-loaders in the `module.preLoaders` section. This doesn't affect the content of this question, and an example with current syntax is available at a [similar article](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html) from the same site.

Comment: Waiting for the answers. I have the same confusion but instead of typescript I'm using ES6 Javascript.

Comment: Same, can't find anywhere online that explain this. I don't understand why it should be a pre-loader, make more sense if it is a post loader: since it say it is processing source-map outputs from typescript.

Comment: I think the answer is that source-map-loader is not needed, at least not in a generic Typescript project..  I use it in node.js to get sensible stack traces etc, but not in webpack.  When running the code in the browser, it resolves the source maps and does the mapping.

Comment: Interesting. If you can find evidence for that supposition, post an answer!

Comment: @jørgen-tvedt, I also have similar suspicion that "source-map-loader"  is not needed. I did play around with ts+webpack setup not using it (https://github.com/ApolloTang/webpack4-babel7-ts3-w-babel-loader). it seem to work just fine; however, it is a setup with babel@7 using @babel/typescript thou.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't have anything to do with TypeScript compilation per se, and you don't need it to get source maps to work for your own sources. However, you probably want it for the following reason, as mentioned in the paragraph right after the one you quoted from `source-map-loader`'s README:

> This loader is especially useful when using 3rd-party libraries having their own source maps. If not extracted and processed into the source map of the webpack bundle, browsers may misinterpret source map data. source-map-loader allows webpack to maintain source map data continuity across libraries so ease of debugging is preserved.

The reason it's a preloader is because it has to be run on `.js` files before they are minified, since that tends to remove inline source maps. Since it only reacts on `.js` files and not `.ts` files it isn't run before your TypeScript files are transpiled, but right after they have been outputted to `.js` files.